# Typescript: Property '...' does not exist on type '{...}[]' next.js project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm new to Typescript and I'm having a hard time to figure out how to make it work this code. I'm building a job application app with Next.JS 14 and using Prisma as my ORM to communicate with my Neon PostgreSQL DB. I believe I need to somehow extend my Interface with my types but I can't make it work. Or maybe I've got everything wrong.

I'm getting the types errors on those lines inside AccordionContent :

```
typeOfUpdate={job?.jobApplicationTimeline.typeOfUpdate as string}
updateDate={job?.jobApplicationTimeline.updateDate as Date}
```

Here we have both components

components/job-applications-card.tsx

```
interface AdminJobApplicationCardProps {
    params: {
        id: string;
    };
  
}
export default async function AdminJobApplicationCard({ 
    params,
}: AdminJobApplicationCardProps) {
    const job = await db.jobApplication.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: params.id
        },
        include: {
            jobApplicationTimeline: {
                orderBy: {
                    updateDate: "asc"
                },
            },
            jobCategory: true,
        }
    })

    return (
        <AccordionContent 
           jobTitle={job?.jobTitle}
           jobApplicationTimeline={job?.jobApplicationTimeline as any[]}
           // TYPES ERROR - Property 'typeOfUpdate' does not exist on type
           // '{ id: string; jobApplicationID: string; typeOfUpdate: 
           // string; updateDate: Date | null; interlocutorName: string | 
           // null; interlocutorMail: string | null; interlocuteurPhone: 
           // string | null;... 6 more ...; updatedAt: Date; }[]' */}
           typeOfUpdate={job?.jobApplicationTimeline.typeOfUpdate as string}
           updateDate={job?.jobApplicationTimeline.updateDate as Date}
         />
```

components/accordion-content.tsx

```
type AccordionContentTypes = {
  jobTitle: string;
  jobApplicationTimeline: any [];

}

interface TimelineProps extends AccordionContentTypes {
  typeOfUpdate: string
  updateDate: Date;
}

const AccordionContent = ({
  jobTitle,
  jobApplicationTimeline,
  typeOfUpdate,
  updateDate,
  
}: TimelineProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Collapse>
            {jobApplicationTimeline?.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="grid grid-cols-8">
                <div className="hidden flex-col gap-0.5 lg:col-span-2 lg:flex"></div>
                <div className="relative col-span-1 mt-1.5">
                  <Text
                    as="span"
                    className="relative z-10 mb-1.5 block h-3 w-3 rounded-full before:absolute before:-left-1.5 before:-top-1.5 before:-z-10 before:h-6 before:w-6 before:rounded-full before:bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 dark:before:bg-gray-50"
                  >
                    <PiPaperPlaneTiltDuotone className="h-3 w-3" />
                  </Text>
                  <Text
                  as="span"
                  className="absolute left-[5px] top-[18px] block h-full w-[2px] bg-gray-200"
                  >

                  </Text>

                </div>

                <div className="col-span-7 flex flex-col pb-9 lg:col-span-5">
                 <Text as="span" className="font-semibold text-gray-900">
                   {dayjs(item.updateDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
                 </Text>
                 <Text as="span" className="text-sm text-gray-900">
                  {item.typeOfUpdate as string}
                </Text>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
      </Collapse>
    </>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Doesn't seems like an issue with the types and works fine on my side. Try restarting the project and your typescript compiler.

Comment: Looks to me like you are accessing member `typeOfUpdate` like this: `job?.jobApplicationTimeline.typeOfUpdate` even though jobApplicationTimeline is (apparently) an array.  This matches up with the error message you are seeing (notice the `[]` on the end of the type they're trying to assign).